# Feeding image to a Django template

Tags: django, templates

I've been working on a simple Django project for myself and I came into a little problem.

When first developing the blog, I didn't make templates, I just made sure things were working properly, but now, I dived into making the templates and everything is working besides my header background-image.

Before the templates, I was doing it like this:

```html
<header class="masthead" style="background-image: url({% static 'img/home-tech-bg.jpg' %})">
```

This was working just fine, but now that I'm trying to do the same as a template it doesn't work. It doesn't return me any errors, but the image doesn't display.

What I did was the following:

**template base.html**

```html
<header class="masthead" style="background-image: url({% block headerimage %} {% endblock %})">
```

**blog.html**

```html
        {% load static %}

        {% block headerimage %}
            {% static 'image/image.jpg' %}
        {% endblock %}
```

What is a better way to do this?

Comment: can you show your project structure?

Comment: @SLDem here is the github repository https://github.com/ofelipesilva/blog

Answer (score 0):

Well first off move your `static` directory to your root directory and write the path in the template like this:

```
{% load static %}

<img src="{% static 'img/home-tech-bg.jpg' %}" alt="/">
```

Also make sure your `settings.py` file is properly configured to serve static files, add this line if you havent yet:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```